# Find the value of the constants $a$ and $b$ such that the following limit is satisfied.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the value of the constants $a$ and $b$ such that the following limit is satisfied.

1. $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{bx-1}{x-a}=\frac12 $.
2. $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{bx+9}{x-a}=a-6 $.
3. $\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{ax+b}{x^2+3x-4}=4$.

I desperately need help with these 3 problems as I do not understand them. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help @oldrinb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(bx-1)/(x-a)\to\frac12$ as $x\to a$ recognize that $bx-1=\frac12(x-a)$. Reduce and equate coefficients:$$bx-1=\frac12(x-a)\\bx-1=\frac12x-\frac{a}2\\\implies b=\frac12,a=2$$

---

Similarly, for our second limit, we see that $bx+9=(a-6)(x-a)$, reduce, and equate coefficients:$$bx+9=(a-6)x-(a-6)a$$Immediately we see that $b=a-6$ and that $-9=(a-6)a=a^2-6a$. Moving terms to our right-hand side, we have a factorizable quadratic equation in $a$:$$a^2-6a+9=0\\(a-3)^2=0\\\implies a=3$$... and thus $b=-3$.

Can you use a similar approach to tackle our third limit?

---

Recognize that our denominator is easily factorizable to yield $x^2+3x-4=(x+4)(x-1)$. Note that since there are no singularities unless $x=a$ and since we have a finite limit and the numerator is only linear we know that cannot be true, we may "distribute" our limit safely to yield:$$\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to a}(ax+b)}{\lim\limits_{x\to a}(x^2+3x-4)}=4\\\frac{a^2+b}{(a+4)(a-1)}=4\\\implies a^2+b=4(a+4)(a-1)$$Expand our right-hand side to yield $4(a+4)(a-1)=4(a^2+3a-4)=4a^2+12a-16$, yielding $$a^2+b=4a^2+12a-16$$Equating coefficients we find $a=0$ and $b=-16$.

Comment: Got that one, ty.

Comment: @MK3GTX check again!

Comment: What I don't understand is bx−1=1/2(x−a)... Wouldn't it be: ba−1=1/2(a−a)?

Comment: No, we are not "plugging in" $x=a$ yet, since $a-a=0$.. the idea is to recognize that we'd only have a finite limit with $x\to a$ if the $x-a$ factor produced a "hole".

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you so much! I would upvote you but I can't :(

Comment: @MK3GTX consider e.g. the limit of $x/x$ as $x\to0$ -- notice it's finite? Now observe what would happen if instead we considered the limit $x/(x-1)$ as $x\to1$. :-)

Comment: It wouldn't exist. Right?

Comment: @MK3GTX precisely, because it's no longer a "hole".

Comment: Thank you so much! My gratitude is approaching infinity.

Comment: No problem! Do you understand why it works out?

Comment: I think I do, haha. I definitely understand why the limit is finite. The way we arrived at the constants was a bit obscure to me, but I'm practicing more problems on paper. Is there a way of checking my answer?

Comment: @MK3GTX sure, substitute your $a,b$ and see if the limit comes out correctly. We're deriving the constants by equating coefficients.

Comment: I get ((1/2)(2)−1)/(2−2) = 0/0. Which is good I think...

Comment: @MK3GTX $0/0$ is an indeterminate form; you want to use a little algebraic manipulation or l'Hopital's rule before you "plug" $x=a$ in. $(\frac12x-1)/(x-2)=\frac12(x-2)/(x-2)=\frac12$.

Comment: Ahhh. The way we were taught was to remove the discontinuity algebraically by relating a and b (which is always were I get stuck). This made everything much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, note that denominator is 0 when $x=a$ so for the limit to exist, the numerator must also equal 0 when $x=a$. This should give you b in terms of a. Now either factorizing of using L'Hopital's Rule, find what the limit would be in terms of a and then solve for the limit to equal 2.

Similar work for the second question.

For the third question consider the cases when a makes the denominator 0 and when it makes the denominator non-zero.